# Creating a dynamic toc.json to use with treesaver.js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I've been working for quite some time with a simple backend (based on Spagent - a flat file blogging script) to use with the amazing javascript library treesaver.js. My problem is that I have a lack in my json skill set and can't for the world figure out how to add arrays to my .json...

My file looks like this:

```
{
  "contents": [
{
  "url": "index.html",
  "hidden": true
},
{
  "url": "section1.html",
  "title": "Section One",
  "thumb": "openroad-thumb.jpg",
  "byline": "John Doe"
},
{
  "url": "one.html",
  "title": "Article One",
  "thumb": "river-thumb.jpg",
  "byline": "Jane Doe"
},
{
  "url": "two.html",
  "title": "Article Two",
  "thumb": "river-thumb.jpg",
  "byline": "Jane Doe"
},
{
  "url": "section2.html",
  "title": "Section Two",
  "thumb": "river-thumb.jpg",
  "byline": "Jane Doe"
},
{
  "url": "three.html",
  "title": "Article Three",
  "thumb": "river-thumb.jpg",
  "byline": "Jane Doe"
},
{
  "url": "four.html",
  "title": "Article Four",
  "thumb": "river-thumb.jpg",
  "byline": "Jane Doe"
},
{
  "url":"five.html",
  "title":"Article Five",
  "thumb":"unknown-thumb.jpeg",
  "byline":"John Doe"
}
  ]
}
```

And when I use these scripts:
*form.php*

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js no-treesaver">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height,initial-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1">
    <title>Treesaver - Article One</title>
  </head>
<body>
<form name="postform" action="post.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table class="postarea" id="postarea">
    <tbody>
<tr>    <td class="postblock">URL:</td><td><input type="text" name="url"></td></tr>
<tr>    <td class="postblock">Titel:</td><td><input type="text" name="title"></td></tr>
<tr>    <td class="postblock">Thumb:</td><td><textarea id="text" rows="5" cols="30" type="text" name="thumb"></textarea> </td> </tr>
<tr>    <td class="postblock">Skribent:</td><td><input type="text" name="byline"></td></tr>

<tr>    <td class="postblock"></td><td> <input type="submit" value="Submit Entry"> </td>    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

*post.php*

```
<?php
// check if a form was submitted
if( !empty( $_POST ) ){

// convert form data to json format
    $postArray = array(
      "url" => $_POST['url'],
      "title" => $_POST['title'],
      "thumb" => $_POST['thumb'],
      "byline" => $_POST['byline']
    );
    //you might need to process any other post fields you have..
$json = json_encode( $postArray);
// make sure there were no problems
//if( json_last_error() != JSON_ERROR_NONE ){
    //exit;  // do your error handling here instead of exiting
// }
$file = 'entries.json';
// write to file
//   note: _server_ path, NOT "web address (url)"!
file_put_contents( $file, $json, FILE_APPEND);  
}
```

My added array is generated like this:

```
{
  "url": "index.html",
  "hidden": true
},
{
  "url": "section1.html",
  "title": "Section One",
  "thumb": "openroad-thumb.jpg",
  "byline": "John Doe"
},
{
  "url": "one.html",
  "title": "Article One",
  "thumb": "river-thumb.jpg",
  "byline": "Jane Doe"
},
{
  "url": "two.html",
  "title": "Article Two",
  "thumb": "river-thumb.jpg",
  "byline": "Jane Doe"
},
{
  "url": "section2.html",
  "title": "Section Two",
  "thumb": "river-thumb.jpg",
  "byline": "Jane Doe"
},
{
  "url": "three.html",
  "title": "Article Three",
  "thumb": "river-thumb.jpg",
  "byline": "Jane Doe"
},
{
  "url": "four.html",
  "title": "Article Four",
  "thumb": "river-thumb.jpg",
  "byline": "Jane Doe"
},
{
  "url":"five.html",
  "headline":"Article Five",
  "thumb":"nagot.jpg",
  "byline":"Gustaf"
}{"url":"six.html","title":"Article Six","thumb":"jasas.jpg","byline":"John Doe"}
```

No comma *,* is generated after my array and the script is broken. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You're appending a fresh JSON object into a file already containing one. You might be able to solve it by prepending a comma to the data you are writing, but I'd say that's the wrong way to solve this. You're trying to write in JSON format directly, but you should be getting PHP to do this for you - it does this very well already, and there's no point re-inventing the wheel.

I would therefore read the contents of the file in, convert it to an object or array as appropriate (using `json_decode`). You can then append things to this structure and re-encode it, before writing the whole thing to a file without the append flag.

If the amount of data in this file is large, you could tackle the problem another way: for every new structure you wish to write, put it in a separate file, and then read them in your blogging script as you need them.

Answer (score 0):

change
`file_put_contents( $file, $json, FILE_APPEND);`

to
`file_put_contents( $file, ",".$json, FILE_APPEND);`

You can put the above statement inside some if statement that checks if the file is not empty since you don't need a comma if you are making first insertion.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response!
Is it possible to put the array first instead of last, since I would like my chapters to be sorted from "latest" to "oldest"?

Answer (score 0):

You would be best advised to read the existing json data and convert it back to its PHP condition which is a Class with the property 'contents' which is an array.

Then you push your new array onto this existing array, and then encode it all as json again and write it all back to your json file.

```
// check if a form was submitted
if( !empty( $_POST ) ){

    $file = 'entries.json';

    $json = file_get_contents($file);

    // convert json back to a php stdClass
    $phpClass = json_decode($json);

    $postArray = array(
         "url" => $_POST['url'],
         "title" => $_POST['title'],
         "thumb" => $_POST['thumb'],
         "byline" => $_POST['byline']
    );

     // push the new $postArray onto the bottom of phpClass
     array_push($phpClass->contents, $postArray);

     // encode php class into json again
     $new_json = json_encode($phpClass);

     // write it out
     file_put_contents( $file, $new_json);
}
```

Comment: So I should replace my content in the post.php file with this?

Comment: This is an example, I didn't use the real post data, read it see what was done and modify your code using this idea not this exact code.

Comment: I hate to ask you this, but would you be an angle and write it out for me by implementing your answer in my code. I get some errors I don't have the coding-experience to get around.. Apologies for my request.

Comment: There you go, hay look ma, I'm an Angel, an Angel I tell you.

Comment: That you are kind sir!

Comment: And if I want the new array to be inserted first in the list. I'm changing this: <pre>array_push($phpClass->contents, $postArray);</pre> to what?

Comment: Try `array_unshift($phpClass->contents, $postArray);` instead of `array_push`